# How can i show result of jquery in inputbox inspite of span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calculated-field

I want to show result of this function in inputbox inspite of tag span because I need to send this result in next form.

```
function checkChange(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "ordercalculate.php",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        context: $("#quote"),
        success: function(data){
            data=parseInt(data);
            $("#quote").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Html Code:

```
<strong>Total Fee: </strong><span id="quote" /><span/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:

```
$('#inputbox').val(data);
```

and your html page should contain textbox as

```
<input type="text" id="inputbox"/>
```

That's it

Answer (score 0):

```
<strong>Total Fee: </strong><input type="text" id="quote" /><span/>
```

You can add the disabled attribute if you don't want the user to change that value.

On the JS side you may want to change :

```
// $("#quote").html(data);
$("#quote").value = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the value to the textbox instead of span.

HTML changes

```
<input type="text" id="txtBox" />
```

Jquery changes

```
$("#txtBox").val(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<strong>Total Fee: </strong><input type="text" name="text" id="quote">

in JS

$("#quote").val(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function checkChange(){
$.ajax({
    url: "ordercalculate.php",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    context: $("#quote"),
    success: function(data){
        data=parseInt(data);
        //$("#quote").html(data);
    $("#quote").val(data);
    }
});
}
```

Html Code:

```
<strong>Total Fee: </strong><input type="text" id="quote" />
```